# How to get path of the file on Server using Java Code?

Tags: java, file, server, ftp

I have uploaded a file on server 'www.server.com'. Now I wish to know the path of the file on the same server through java code. Is there any specific method or process present? I am new to this.

```
public class Test {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test test = new test();
        String server ="www.server.com";
        int port = 21;
        String username = "abc";
        String password = "abc`enter code here`";

        FTPClient ftpclient = new FTPClient();


        try {
            ftpclient.connect(server, port);
            ftpclient.login(username, password);
            ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpclient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            File firstLocalFile = new File("D:\\ADF\\Tax Files\\TERData.zip");

            String firstRemoteFile = "TERData.zip";

            InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);
            System.out.println("Start Uploading the First File");

            System.out.println(" File Path ":+firstLocalFile.getAbsolutePath());

            boolean done = ftpclient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputstream);

            if(done){
                System.out.println(" File successfully uploaded ");
            }                              
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: Add catch code
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try printing `ftpclient.printWorkingDirectory();`

Comment: I tried using that it did print me the directory but actually it is not the directory i need.

Comment: Which directory has that printed???

Comment: The issue is the when i log in through port 22 i see the directory i want.But  when I log in  through port 21 that directory is not present.But the file is present.The above method call gives me the directory path of file when i  log in through port 21 which i dont want. Can you help me with this

Comment: I think telnet uses 22 port. 21 is used for FTP.

Comment: Can you try with port 20? Both 20 and 21 are used by FTP. Also has port 21 been opened by firewall?

Comment: So is there any possibllity of uploading the file using port 22?

Comment: I think you can upload file without necessarily depending on the port. But, there should be some contract between server and client. More of a networking think than programming.

Comment: Hi harshavmb thank you for ur help

Answer (score 0):

```
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            try {

                ftpClient.connect(server, port);
                ftpClient.login(user, pass);
                ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                 FTPFile[] files1 = ftpClient.listFiles("/test");//"/test/test.txt";
String remoteFile1 =files1[0].getName();
                File downloadFile1 = new File("D:/Downloads/test.mp4");
                OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
                boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
                outputStream1.close();

                if (success) {
                    System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
                }
```

Comment: By printing remoteFile1 will i get the path of the uploaded file on the server?

Comment: No this is an example. If you see ftpclient return a file object so you can get the path also.please explore ftpfile object.I will update my ans